# Process finished with exit code 2

Tags: python

Whenever I am trying to run a object detection program in pycharm, the following error occurs (see the trace). Could you please help to figure out, how to fix it?

```
C:\Users\Dell\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 11093 --file C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/image.py
pydev debugger: process 2648 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 183.5429.31)
usage: image.py [-h] -i IMAGE -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
image.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -p/--prototxt, -m/--model

Process finished with exit code 2
```

### Actually i am trying to run the code in the following page

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/
My question is where should i copy and paste .......python deep_learning_object_detection.py \
    --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt \
    --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --image images/example_01.jpg

Comment: But error message tells, that required parameters are missing. Could you post script body of image.py file then? Did you try to add those arguments to the script code?

Comment: Instead of trying with pycharm. Try it with cmd and check whether that throws same error too.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, in the `Run` menu, look for `Edit configurations...`

Each time you run a new script, a run configuration is created for it and it is here that you can provide command line parameters in the `Parameters:` box.

You probably only want to past the parameters section there, not the script name, so:

```
\ --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt \ --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --image images/example_01.jpg
```

Another issue you may run into is what working directory your script needs to run in. You can change it from the same dialog, under `Working directory:`. You'll find that you'll rarely need to change any of the other fields in this dialog, although I would recommend giving it a name that's sensible to you under `Name:` - by default it's named after the script file it is running.

Comment: i am pasting ....\ --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt \ --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel --image images/example_01.jpg in parameters box as u said.and keeping working directory....C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\object-detection-deep-learning .....then clicking on run to run the program in pycharm,still ............process finished with exit code 2.....error is coming